# RDA, Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric, when data is numeric?

Tags: r, vegan, rda

I want to perform a rda in R, using vegan.

My code looks like this:

```
species<- read.delim("springspecies1.txt", header=T)
envdata<- read.delim("springenv1.txt", header=T)

RDA <- rda(species~Temperature + Salinity + O2 + Phosphate + Nitrate + Silica, envdata, scale=T, na.action=na.omit)
```

and I get the error message:

```
Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
```

when I check my data I get:

```
sapply(species, mode)
      Station          Year         Month     S.marinoi      C.tripos 
    "numeric"     "numeric"     "numeric"     "numeric"     "numeric" 
      P.alata     P.seriata    R.setigera    C.pelagica D.confervacea 
    "numeric"     "numeric"     "numeric"     "numeric"     "numeric" 
  C.decipiens    P.farcimen       C.furca 
    "numeric"     "numeric"     "numeric"
```

There are no NA or blanks in my data set. But it seems that the species data set is the problem. I compiled a new data set with the species, but I get the same problem again. Any ideas?

Comment: You probably have factors.   Use `sapply(species, class)`, not `mode`,  since `mode` will still give `numeric` for `factor`s

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of using 'mode', you should be testing with 'class'. You probably have a factor column. They are of mode numeric  but test FALSE with 'is.numeric'.

Comment: Userul answers are supposed to be upvoted. The "most correct" answers gets checkmarked. (Please read the FAQ.)